# C# XmlDocument: Nested objects

Tags: c#, xmlreader

I have a XML file that has this following format:

```
<datasources>
    <datasource name="...">
        <column caption="..." name="..."> ... </column>
        <column caption="..." name="..."> ... </column>
    </datasource>
    <datasource name="...">
        <column caption="..." name="..."> ... </column>
        <column caption="..." name="..."> ... </column>
    </datasource>
</datasources>
...
```

and I want to get a `caption`-`name` map for `columns` that meets specific criteria (that is, has an expected `caption` and is a `column` of an expected `datasource`).

Currently I have this code but I'm not confident of it.

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(content));
while (reader.ReadToFollowing("datasource"))
{
    reader.MoveToAttribute("name");
    if (reader.Value == dsName)
    {
        while (reader.ReadToFollowing("column"))
        {
            reader.MoveToAttribute("caption");
            if (captions.Contains(reader.Value))
            {
                String cap = reader.Value;
                reader.MoveToAttribute("name");
                local_caps.Add(new KeyValuePair<String, String>(reader.Value, cap));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My concern is that, would the inner `while` loop (looking for all `column`s) read all the way towards the end of the file and hence go out of its supposed scope (within its `datasource`)? If so, how should I avoid it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is ideal job for [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/):

```
doc.Load("file.xml");
var nodes = doc.SelectNodes("/datasources/datasource[@name='DS1']/column[@caption='C1']");
```

Of course, to get your map, you have to improve this sample a little:

```
string expectedDatasource = "DS1";
string expectedCaption = "C1";
string xpath = string.Format("/datasources/datasource[@name='{0}']/column[@caption='{1}']",
                             expectedDatasource, expectedCaption)
var local_caps = doc.SelectNodes(xpath)
                    .Cast<XmlElement>()
                    .ToDictionary(x => x.GetAttribute("name"), 
                                  x => x.GetAttribute("caption"));
```